# Hit Highlighting Blob Data

Tags: sql

Hi ive currently been trying to do some full text searching on some .docx files stored as BLOB data in my database. Ive been trying to bring back a snippet of these documents in a google like fashion. Ive currently been following the example in the Apress Pro Full Text Searching book. However the example doesnt use BLOB data, does anyone know if what im trying to do is possible with this method ? thanks.

Comment: what type of DBMS do you use? /i.e. Oracle, MySQL, etc./

Comment: OK, so I looked up the book you referred and it seems you use MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible. Internally SQL server stores the list of occurrence values that correspond to relative offsets of the particular keyword within the document. Please refer to the Occ column in the index structure in this [article about full text search internals in MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#yukonftsea_topic3)

I am not sure whether you have to implement your own CONTAINS or you can configure SQL server to return the occurrence values to your query. Should you figure it out, please follow this thread up.

Once you have the occurrence values returned in your result set, it is up to your application to get a snippet from the blob.